# Insert checkbox value in mysql DB

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am learning PHP and I have a problem with inserting the checkbox values into my db,
Please tell me what is wrong. Thank U

How can I fix this code to store all checked values?

```
<html>
<body>
    <form action="submit.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="checkbox" name="ch[]" id="ch" value="JAVA">JAVA <br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="ch[]" id="ch" value="C++">C++ <br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="ch[]" id="ch" value="JS">JS <br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="ch[]" id="ch" value="C">C <br>
        <input type="button" value="submit" name="submit">
    </form>
    <?php
try {
            $bdd = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test;charset=utf8', 'root', '');
        } catch (Exception $th) {
            die('Error'.$th->getMessage());
        }
        if(isset($_POST["submit"])){
            $check =implode(',',$_POST['ch']);
            $qry = $bdd->prepare("INSERT INTO test inputC VALUES ('$check')");    
            $res=mysql_query($qry);
            if($res){
                echo "insert success";
            }else{
                echo "error in inserting";
                }
            }
        ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What happens when your execute the code?

Comment: Nothing at all :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your form submission button is not configured properly, it should be `<button type="submit" name="submit">Submit</button>`. Also the SQL query is not being executed as that is not how it is done with `PDO`.

Here is a possible solution:

```
...
<body>
    <form method="post" action="submit.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="checkbox" name="ch[]" id="ch" value="JAVA">JAVA <br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="ch[]" id="ch" value="C++">C++ <br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="ch[]" id="ch" value="JS">JS <br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="ch[]" id="ch" value="C">C <br>
        <button type="submit" name="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
    <?php
    try {
        $bdd = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test;charset=utf8', 'root', '');
        $bdd->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    } catch (Exception $th) {
        die('Error'.$th->getMessage());
    }

    if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
        try {
            $check = implode(',',$_POST['ch']);
            $stmt = $bdd->prepare("INSERT INTO test (inputC) VALUES (?)");  

            $stmt->execute([$check]);

            if ($bdd->lastInsertId() != -1) {
                echo "insert success";
            } else {
                echo "error in inserting";
            }
        } catch(PDOException $e) {
            die("Error: ".$e->getMessage());
        }
    }
}
?>
</body>
...
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution, but I still have a problem, the Data base is always empty even though php prints "insert success".

Comment: @ArbaniOumaima Have you including all the changes including the line `$bdd->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);`?

Comment: Yeah right now it is working, but could you please explain the purpose of that line. Thank U

Comment: @ArbaniOumaima That line tells PDO to treat all errors as exceptions which allows the `try... catch..` to capture them all.